# How to allow remote connection to SQL Server instance only to specific public IP Address (white-list) & restrict access to all other IP's

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, remote-access, firewall

How do I allow remote connection to SQL Server instance only to specific public IP Address (white-list)?

For example, login from SSMS to SQL Server instance hosted on Windows dedicated server allowing access only from specific public IP.

Also, the need to restrict access to all other IP's, i,e to prevent login from SSMS

Comment: This is really not a programming-related question in any way - it's about systems setup, firewall configuration etc. -> those questions belong on https://serverfault.com

Comment: Fine. I will post in serverfault.com

Comment: @AnirudhShankar : Could you please link me to the question?